# Solutions for virtualized Windows on Linux. Good performance needed

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, xen

What are good solutions for virtualized Windows on Linux? I need good system performance.

I use Xen for Linux virtualization on my work machines, can Xen be used for Windows as well?

I also used VirtualBox in the past, but the performance wasn't best.

Any other options?

Comment: Xen was used to virtualize windows instances on a college campus where I worked.  It's possible.  I can't comment on performance between all the virtualization solutions though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inferior VM performance is usually because the guest is running in "HVM" mode
(Hardware Virtualized Mode, or Fully-Virtualized Mode).  While this may allow
you to run an unmodified system in a virtual machine, all of the I/O devices are
emulated in software.  So, if you use a network interface card (NIC) a device
driver in the guest communicates with a driver in the host system running VBOX;
this driver pretends to be a network interface card, responding to
register-level reads and writes.  Once the emulated NIC software decides what
the VM guest really wants, it forwards a request to the actual device driver in
the VBOX host.  Sound inefficient?  You bet it is.

To improve the situation, VBOX provides "Guest Additions" for most guest O/S's.
These are actually some relatively simple device drivers that know how to
communicate with the host's device drivers using high-level commands instead of
hardware register reads and writes.  Using these para-virtualization drivers,
you should get only a few percent performance degradation over a bare-metal
install.

You may want to try Oracle VM which installs onto bare-metal and supports both
Linux and Windows guests.  Para-virtualized add-on drivers are available for
Windows.  There are even pre-configured Linux templates similar to VMWare
appliances.  No pre-configured Windows because it isn't redistributable, but
add-on drivers are available.  Check it out at http://www.oracle.com/oraclevm,
it's free to download and free to use.  Commercial support is available.

Comment: Oracle VM == VirtualBox (aka VBOX)